# difference in time is giving incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table as test

```
shiftend            |        out            |       
---------------------------------------------   
15:00:00.0000000    |   2016-07-22 14:42:00 |   
16:00:00.0000000    |   2016-07-22 16:06:00 |
```

Shiftend is having a datatype as time
out is having a datatype as smalldatetime

I am expecting the output as

```
shiftend            |         out           |   Output    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   
15:00:00.0000000    |   2016-07-22 14:42:00 |   -00:18:00   
16:00:00.0000000    |   2016-07-22 16:06:00 |    00:06:00
```

I am trying this query:

```
select shiftend,out,CAST((out-Shiftend) as time(0)) as Output from test
where 
CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), out, 101) AS SMALLDATETIME) = CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),'2016-07-22', 101) AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

But i am getting the output as

```
shiftend            |   out                 |     Output    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   
15:00:00.0000000    |   2016-07-22 14:42:00 |    23:42:00   
16:00:00.0000000    |   2016-07-22 16:06:00 |    00:06:00
```

23:42:00 is incorrect. How to calcualte the time.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't have negative values in the `time` datatype. It's turning -18 into (00:00 - 00:18) which is 23:42 the previous day. You could:

- Use `datediff` and save the difference as the number of seconds for example.
- Save only the modular difference and have a separate column for deciding whether it's a positive or negative difference.
- Write your own SQL function for computing this

Comment: if its not giving me negative can we get only 00:18, that will be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
select 
 case when (cast(out as time) < shiftend) then '-' else '' end + 
 convert(varchar(8), 
  dateadd(minute, 
   abs(
    DATEDIFF(minute, 
     cast(out as time)
    , shiftend)
   )
 ,0)
,108) as Output
```

Explanation:

- You're getting the difference between the two dates with `DATEDIFF(minute, cast(out as time), shiftend)`.
- You need just the `time` component to avoid going to the previous day, so you use `cast(out as time)`. `shiftend` as you mentioned is already of datatype `time`
- `abs` returns the absolute value, so -18 becomes 18.
- Then generate a date by adding the above value as minutes to `00:00:00` using `dateadd(minute, [above value], 0)`
- The final `convert(varchar(8),____,108)` is since you required the output as a time.
- `iif(cast(out as time) < shiftend,'-','')` adds negative sign or not to the beginning of the word.

Unfortunately, you can't have negative values in the `time` datatype. It's turning -18 into 00:00 - 18 which is 23:42. You could:

- Use `datediff` and save the difference as the number of seconds for example.
- Save only the modular difference and have a separate column for deciding whether it's a positive or negative difference.
- Write your own SQL function for computing this as a `varchar` as above

Comment: your query giving an error 'Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: Can you run this query: `select iif(cast(out as time) < shiftend,'-','') from test`?

Comment: Modified my answer...try it now. `IIF` isn't available in sql server 2008 only in 2012.

Comment: No worries mate : )